# Open Android options menu from method

Tags: android, menu, android-sdk-2.3, touch-event, android-menu

I know that it's possible because I've done it before, but i lost my code. I want to open the Menu from an touch event. What do I need to write to open it? I really don't know anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)` and `onContextItemSelect()` in activity. 
If you want it to appear on long click then call `registerForContextMenu(View)`. If you want to show it manually on clicking any view then call `openContextMenu()` in onClick().

Comment: Your title and description differ. You say context menu in your title and not options menu.